# Python 2.7 not compiling recipes for ios build

Tags: python, ios, kivy

I'm attempting to build an ios app with kivy but am having issues with recipes not compiling.  I do not have a Mac so I'm using a dedicated server with Macincloud.  They have Python 2.7 already installed and upon trying to upgrade to Python 3.8, I was running into issues.  So I reset the server and started over but with using Python 2.7.

However, I'm getting an error that Macincloud support cannot help with and I'm not able to find a solution after extensive research.  The error occurs after running the ./toolchain.py command as it results in the following:  "No python recipes compiled!, You must have compiled at least python2 or python3 recipes to be able to create a project".

Any thoughts or insight as to what the problem may be and possible solutions are much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you need python2 or python3 in your requirements, but you have neither.

Comment: Thanks, Inclement!  How would I go about adding those to the requirements. I think I followed the steps outlined in kivy documentation but maybe something isn't inserting it correctly and I'm new to programming overall and don't really know what to look for in it.

Comment: I'm looking at the toolchain.py and also the requirements.txt files and am not sure if I need to add something to either one for Python2.  Any thoughts on it?  Thanks!